# What's wrong with my basic sequential model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This is my input,

```
x_input = tf.constant([[1,2.]], shape = (1,2))
```

And the output is:

```
[[0.2692713  0.46113062 0.6706152 ]
[0.51462847 0.5941784  0.6396018 ]]
```

I wanted to do this in the sequential model, so I did this,

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4,batch_input_shape=(None,1,2),use_bias= True,bias_initializer='zeros')) 

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,batch_size = 2, activation = "sigmoid", use_bias = True))
```

But I got this, `[[0.07918601 0.38569203 0.927532]]`

How can I get the desired result using a sequential model? Is there any way to change the weight and bias shape?

Comment: what's the desired result? what's wrong?

Comment: I need the output as (2,3) shape using sequential model. But my sequential model is giving me (1,3) output. I don't understand the problem with my model.

Comment: if you pass shape `(1, ...)` it will output `(1, ...)` because you have one row as input and you will always have 1 row as output (at least with a sequential model)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because what you're asking isn't clear

Answer (score 2):

This is multiclass-classification (last layer outputs more than 2) hence use activation as "softmax"

The output you will get is the probability of each class.

If you want class labels: use `np.argmax()` as following

```
classes = np.argmax(model.predict(x))
print(classes)
```

Comment: My preferred output is in (2,3) shape, whereas my input is in (1,2) shape. But my sequential model is giving me output as (1,2) . How can I change my sequential model to get the output in (2,3) shape?

Comment: Try using the "softmax" activation in last layer. "sigmoid" is used in binary classification

Comment: class OurDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, n_output_nodes):  
        super(OurDenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.n_output_nodes = n_output_nodes
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        d = int(input_shape[-1])
        self.W = self.add_weight("weight", shape = [d, self.n_output_nodes]) 
        self.b = self.add_weight("bias", shape = [d, self.n_output_nodes]) 
                                
     def call(self, x):
        z = tf.matmul(x, self.W)+self.b
        y = tf.math.sigmoid(z)
        return y

Comment: I did this to get the (2,3) output at first. By the way, Softmax didn't work.